# How to get latest (recent) tag in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to get latest (newest) tag in the WordPress site. I search a lot but didn't found any solution.

Please help

Thanks

Comment: do you mean the latest tag 'side-wide' or the latest tag associated with a post?

Comment: I want latest tag around the site. The last tag that added to my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$args = array(
    'number' => 1,
    'order' => DESC
);
$tags = get_tags( $args );

foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
    $tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );  
    $html = "<a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name}' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
    $html .= "{$tag->name}</a>";
    echo $html;
}
```

**EDITED** to display the most recent tag. See comments for details.

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags

Comment: Thanks for your attention. This is only return first (oldest) tag. I change your code according to your reference article to get latest tag and some improvement.

Answer (score 0):

I see, you need to get wordpress **tag name** 
I'm going to write a very simple script to show **tag_name**

```
<?php 

 // Get value from wordpress get_tags() function and stored in $your_tag variable
 $your_tag = get_tags();

 // Check if has tag          
 if( $your_tag ){

 // Fetch data from array argument using foreach loop
 foreach( $your_tag as $tag_single ) {

     echo '<li><a href="'. esc_url( get_tag_link( $tag_single->term_id ) ) .'">'." $tag_single->name ".'</a></li>'; 

   }        
}

?>
```

For more information please check

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags